# Ubuntu not starting

Tags: boot, boot-failure, live-cd, iso

I have already burned Ubuntu to the disk. But after restarting I am not getting the language selection screen or any other option to install or try Ubuntu.

Comment: What do you mean "clack screen"? Did you change the boot sequence to boot from CD first? How did you burn the CD?

Answer (score 0):

You have an UEFI or EFI computer UEFI is going to replace bios in a while.
When you just boot the live cd or flash drive without entering the boot menu its going to load ubuntu like an app. When your computer starts up you will see your manufacturer logo and it will show boot options on the buttom like f* to boot etc.
Choose your flashdrive or cd drive from the boot menu and it should load a purple screen.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer?

Comment: Usually when your computer starts and shows the manufacturer stuff etc. Usually f* brings you to boot menu and you select your live cd or flashdrive

Comment: Edit your answer so future users can clearly understand this.